# The event listener method class 'com.logic.SomeBean' is not an instance of the actual bean class 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        if (some condition...) {
            return new SomeBean();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the bean class is

```
public class SomeBean {
    @EventListener
    public void handleSomeEvent() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Now, if the `someBean()` method returning null, and the event `SomeEvent` is published, I am getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The event listener method class 'com.logic.SomeBean' is not an instance of the actual bean class 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'. If the bean requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.
HandlerMethod details: 
Bean [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean]
Method [public void com.logic.SomeBean.handleSomeEvent(com.events.SomeEvent)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=com.events.SomeEvent] [value=com.events.SomeEvent[source=com.events.SomeEventPublisher@13ee1d20]]

    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.assertTargetBean(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:330) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:264) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

Why spring still know the bean `SomeBean` even its method returned null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By returning null from the bean method `someBean()`, Spring create object of NullBean, and register it as the bean for SomeBean.

You should, if possible, extract the logic in "some condition..." to use [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation, to use on the method `someBean()`, or to use [profiling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html).

A work around for this, is to change the method someBean() to return an interface, lets say ISomeBean, that SomeBean will inherit from. Like that, spring will not scan the `@EventListener` of SomeBean class.